# Do Ruby/Rails state machines exist that execute event transitions when a state change occurs?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

Hopefully this isn't a silly question and I'm just not overlooking something in Ruby/Rails state machines (AASM, Transitions, AlterEgo, etc).

From what I can tell, these state machine implementations operate on the preface that an event will get fired and the appropriate transition for that event will be triggered based on the old and new state. However, they don't seem to work the other way; say a user wants to change state from 'created' to 'assigned' and have the correct transition occur, rather than firing the event that causes the current state to be transitioned to the new state.

Essentially, I want the user to be able to select a new state from a select box of available states and have the appropriate transition, guards, success callbacks, etc., executed.

Does anyone know if the existing state machine implementations support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are trying to do with my gem flojo.
Just name events after states and have those events trigger a transition from the wildcard state to the state selected in the drop down.

If you have a state "pending" in your drop down, you can configure a flojo event using the following snippet

```
event :pending do
  # :any is a wildcard state and is only valid as a begin state.
  transition :any, :pending
end
```

After your form is submitted, you would then have to prefix "pending" with "wf_", convert it to a symbol and then send it to your object. It would be cleaner to just create a method in your class that does the prefixing and symbol conversion, and then delegates to send.

```
your_object.send :wf_pending
```

https://github.com/alternegro/flojo

Answer (score 2):

State machines, by their nature, do not permit you to arbitrarily jump to any state in the system. Each has an entry point, and each time you wish to change state, some conditions are evaluated (one of which may be the input event) and the next state is a result of those conditions. You could have a state machine with transitions defined from each state to each other state, though.

```
class Ticket
  acts_as_state_machine :initial => :new

  state :new
  state :open
  state :resolved

  event :open do
    transitions :to => :open, 
      :from => [:new, :resolved], :guard => :can_be_open?
  end

  event :new do
    transitions :to => :new, 
      :from => [:open, :resolved], :guard => :can_be_new?
  end

  event :resolved do
    transitions :to => :resolved,
      :from => [:open, :new], :guard => :can_be_resolved?
  end

  private

  def can_be_resolved?
    !resolution.blank?
  end

  ...

end

@ticket = Ticket.create
@ticket.state # => new
@ticket.resolved!
@ticket.state # => resolved
```

So, you would need to check the desired state from the dropdown, and invoke the proper transition as a result. You could use something as simple as `attr_accessor :new_state`, and then a `new_state => event` mapping or case statement that your model invokes `before_validation`.

Comment: Ok, so I guess the key point to take away here is there can be event names that match state names such that select box values can be state names and can be used with 'model#send' to trigger an event. Right?